# Tensorflow.js model.fit does not accept String values

Tags: string, integer, tensor, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow.js

the problem is here:

```
const trainingData = tf.tensor2d(horses.map(item => [

            item.horse_sf   // <- if item.x value is integer, I don't have a problem    
    ]))


model.fit(trainingData,outputData, {epochs: 100})
      .then((history) => {
        // console.log(history)
        var pred = model.predict(testingData);
      var readable_output = pred.dataSync(); 
      console.log(readable_output);
      })
```

**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'gather' must be numeric tensor, but got string tensor**

Why am I having this error, and how can I solve this?

Comment: `tf.fit()` takes in a a tf.Tensor object that represents an immutable, multidimensional array of numbers that has a shape and a data type. So you cannot pass in string values. Could you add in an example of the data being passed in?

Answer (score 0):

A neural network is a mathematical structure. It starts with multiple inputs, these numbers will get calculated further in the network. So it must be an integer, cause you can't do math with strings.

To solution for your problem depends on your data. I think your database exists of a number of horses and their attributes. So, lets say you have 3 different types of horses. Give every horse an id, so 'Morgan' --> 1, 'Quarter Horse' --> 2, 'Pony' --> 3.

Do this also with the attributes you have for your horses that aren't an integer or float already.

Then your model will be able to calculate.

Comment: there is already an id for every horse. I want to refer to the horses' sf_number for example which is a String, as the horse's id won't help in calculating anything. parseInt() also is not an option.

Comment: What is the horse's sf_number? Does it contain letters and digits?

Comment: If it always is DDDLDDDDDD, then you can split it in 3 inputs: DDD will be the first input. DDDDDD the third input. For the second input you can convert the letter into a digit, given  A-->1, B-->2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question:

`item.horse_sf   // <- if item.x value is integer, I don't have a problem`

The inputs and outputs of a neural network can only be numbers; namely integers or floats. If your `horse_sf` value is a mixture of integers and letters, you are going to have to change it to some purely numerical value to train a neural network on it.